# How and what version of SSMS do I have to install after installing VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, 64-bit, sql-server-2008

I installed VS 2010 on a plain Vista x64 OS, now I need to install SSMS as well.
Based on your experience, what version do I have to install?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested many ways till I came up to this clean conclusion:
From my experience, if you use a x64 sys, install VS without SQL, then install SQL x64 separately.

That worked for me, will save you hell of a lot grief.